# In python django how do you print out an object's introspection? The list of all public methods of that object (variable and/or functions)?

Tags: python, django

In python django how do you print out an object's inrospection?  The list of all public methods of that object (variable and/or functions)?

e.g.:

```
def Factotum(models.Model):
  id_ref = models.IntegerField()

  def calculateSeniorityFactor():
    return (1000 - id_ref) * 1000
```

I want to be able to run a command line in the Django shell to tell me all of the public methods of a Django model.  The output of running on above would be:

```
>> introspect Factotoum
--> Variable: id_ref
--> Methods: calculateSeniorityFactor
```

Answer (score 51):

Well, things you can introspect are many, not just one.

Good things to start with are:

```
>>> help(object)
>>> dir(object)
>>> object.__dict__
```

Also take a look at the inspect module in the standard library.

That should make 99% of all the bases belong to you.

Answer (score 6):

Use [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html?highlight=inspect#inspect.getmembers):

```
import inspect
def introspect(something):
  methods = inspect.getmembers(something, inspect.ismethod)
  others = inspect.getmembers(something, lambda x: not inspect.ismethod(x))
  print 'Variable:',   # ?! what a WEIRD heading you want -- ah well, w/ever
  for name, _ in others: print name,
  print
  print 'Methods:',
  for name, _ in methods: print name,
  print
```

There's no way you can invoke this without parentheses in a normal Python shell, you'll have to use `introspect(Factotum)` ((with class `Factotum` property imported in the current namespace of course)) and **not** `introspect Factotum` with a space.  If this irks you terribly, you may want to look at [IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/).